# Interpreting output for nodemix() terms in an ergm model estimated using R

Tags: r

I'm using the `ergm` R package to try to find out whether individuals from certain groups are more (or less) likely to form a tie (to interact, in this particular case).

I'm having trouble interpreting the output. In particular, when I use an `ergm-term`, e.g., `nodefactor()`, what is estimated (if I understand correctly) is the log odds of *any* tie (i.e., sending or receiving) involving each level of the factor.

For `nodemix()`, though, when I don't specify which particular node factor pairings should be included and so all are, there seems to be an order, i.e. a term for the pairing that includes both the Teacher and Administration ties (i.e., `mix.profile_code.Teacher.Administration` as well as those that include the Administration and Teacher ties (`mix.profile_code.Administration.Teacher`.

My questions:

- does sender/receiver status not matter for `nodefactor()`? Is there a way to specify `nodefactor()` for sender and receiver seperately?
- for `nodemix(), does the order matter, with the first value in the pair representing the sender, and the second the receiver (i.e., for`mix.profile_code.Teacher.Administration`, Teacher is the sender, and Administration receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using the ergm package, so I can only point out that [the package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ergm/ergm.pdf) lists ***nodeifactor*** and ***nodeofactor***, for *Factor attribute effect for in-degree* and *out-edges*. As to interpreting them, I'm working on that myself.